# How to make the onClick event only fire when the element is deliberately clicked and not when the click "started" from another element

Tags: javascript, event-listener

In the snippet below, if you:

- Click down in the red `<div>` and hold the click down
- Then move the cursor to the blue `<body>` (without releasing yet)
- Then release the click when you are in the blue `<body>`

Then `e.target` counts the click as a click on the `<body>` even though the click actually happened to the `<div>` element

My scenario is a side menu which should close when the body is clicked, however, I do NOT want the  menu to close if the click originated from the menu but was released over the body like what is happening in my snippet. Is this possible to do?

PS: Just to clarify, I am just trying to understand this behavior and how you could get the click's start element instead of whatever it is that is going on right now. I am not asking how to build the menu or anything.

I am also noticing that if you start the click in the `<body>` and then release it over the `<div>`, it still counts as a click to the `<body>`. This is the opposite effect of what I demonstrated above which is confusing me even further. Is this because it always chooses the greater ancestor of the start and release elements?? I can`t seem to get any results about this when Googling.

PS: I am using google chrome in case this behavior is browser specific.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 10rem;
  background: turquoise;
}
.div {
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">Click Down Here</div>
Release Here
```

Comment: Click event on MDN says: "If the button is pressed on one element and the pointer is moved outside the element before the button is released, the event is fired on the most specific ancestor element that contained both elements." So, when you click the div and release it over the body, the most specific ancestor containing both elements is body. But, if you click the body and release it over the div, the event target will still be body because the cursor never left it.

Comment: @YılmazKasap That cleared things up a lot, thank you! Do you know if there is a way to get the less specific ancestor in any way? I checked that e.relatedTarget does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting up two event listeners. Listen mousedown event and save its target element. On mouseup event you could compare your variables and figure out whether both mousedown and mouseup took place on the same element.

```js
let clickedElement;

document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  clickedElement = e.target.id;
});

document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  const releasedElement = e.target.id;
  if (clickedElement === releasedElement) {
  console.log(`Directly clicked on ${clickedElement}`);
  }
  clickedElement = undefined;
});
```

```css
#body {
  height: 10rem;
  background: turquoise;
  user-select: none;
}
#div {
  height: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
   <div id="div">Click Down Here</div>
   Release Here
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Most (not all) events "bubble" up the DOM tree. They fire on the original target element, and then on the chain of parent elements up to the top of the DOM. This is an **extremely** useful feature, as it allows events to be handled by global top-level handlers without the need to attach handlers all over the place in the DOM.

On the `event` element that's passed to an event handler, the "target" property will give you the original element involved in the event (the "click" or whatever).  The "currentTarget" property will give you the element that is currently called, one of the parents of the target. You can use the `.matches()` API in a top-level handler to decide if and how to handle an event from the actual target:

```
function globalListener(event) {
  const targ = event.target;
  if (targ.matches(".some-button")) {
    handleButton(targ);
  }
  // ...
}
```

If you *don't* want to handle an event on a parent element, you can check if the "target" and "currentTarget" elements are different.

You can use the `event.stopPropagation()` method to tell the browser to stop bubbling an event up the tree, or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to stop calling handlers for the event entirely.

*edit* — for your case of the side menu, you can check if the target matches an element that's a descendant of the menu container:

```
// handler on the body
function clickHandler(event) {
  if (event.target.matches(".menu-container *"))
    return; // do nothing
}
```

Comment: This is very useful information about eventlisteners, however, the problem I am describing is about how e.target is evaluated when the element where the click started from is different from the element it is released over. Right now event.target will always be "the most specific ancestor element that contained both elements" as @Yılmaz Kasap described. I am however trying to only fire the event for "direct" clicks, but I am beginning to believe it is not possible without replacing it with the less desireable mousedown

Comment: @OscarR that's in the answer: if the event handler is called on a *parent* element, then `event.currentTarget` will be *different* from `event.target`. The "target" gives the original element where the event fired, and the "currentTarget" gives the parent element.

Comment: @OscarR and yes, when the browser makes a decision about what to do when the mouse has moved (or other "weird" situations), there's nothing you can do about that, and in most cases you probably can't even detect it happened. In general I'd say it's probably not worth trying, in terms of usability. Your pages should behave the way other pages on other sites do.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up! "Your pages should behave the way other pages on other sites do" Thats a really good point actually.

Comment: `.matches` was such an amazing addition to the dom api!